# Python regex \number adding \0x

Tags: python, regex, replace

I am tring to go a simple regex replace on a string in python. This is my code:

```
>>> s = "num1 1 num2 5"
>>> re.sub("num1 (.*?) num2 (.*?)","1 \1 2 \2",s)
```

I would expect an output like this, with the `\number`s being replaced with their corresponding groups.

```
'1 1 2 5'
```

However, this is the output I am getting:

```
'1 \x01 2 \x025'
```

And I'm kinda stumped as to why the `\x0`s are their, and not what I would like to be there. Many thanks for any help

Comment: if you just want all numbers: `' '.join(re.findall(r'\d+', 'num1 1 num2 5'))`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to start using raw strings (prefix the string with r):

```
>>> import re
>>> s = "num1 1 num2 5"
>>> re.sub(r"num1 (.*?) num2 (.*?)", r"1 \1 2 \2", s)
'1 1 2 5'
```

Otherwise you would need to escape your backslashes both for python and for the regex, like this:

```
>>> re.sub("num1 (.*?) num2 (.*?)", "1 \\1 2 \\2", s)
'1 1 2 5'
```

(this gets really old really fast, check out the opening paragraphs of the [python regex docs](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html)

Comment: +1. To clarify a bit: without the `r`, the `\1` and `\2` are octal (base-8) character escapes, so `"1 \1 2 \2"` means a string whose third character is the ASCII character with value `1`, and whose seventh character is the ASCII character with value `2`. Those characters aren't printing characters, so the command-line pretty-printer replaces them with hexadecimal character escapes, `\x01` and `\x02`. But the `\x0` isn't in the actual string, it's just in what gets printed.

Answer (score 1):

`\1` and `\2` are getting interpreted as octal character code escapes, rather than just getting passed to the regex engine. Using raw strings `r"\1"` instead of `"\1"` prevents this interpretation.

```
>>> "\17"
'\x0f'
>>> r"\17"
'\\17'
```

Answer (score 1):

The `\1` is being interpreted in the string. So you must escape the `\` with its own backslash:

```
>>> re.sub("num1 (.*?) num2 (.*?)", "1 \\1 2 \\2",s)
'1 1 2 5'
```

You can also use a *raw* string:

```
>>> re.sub("num1 (.*?) num2 (.*?)", r"1 \1 2 \2",s)
'1 1 2 5'
```